# Azure Search for Person macthing with multiple fields and scoring profile

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am trying to see if i can use Azure search to do a Person match. i try to match person based on different attributes score them based on match and higher than certain threshold is considered that this person is a match against my azure search data-set.

i have defined scoring profile in my index as such, giving different weight to different attribute.

```
                ScoringProfiles = new[]
                {
                    new ScoringProfile()
                    {
                        Name = SuggesterName,
                        TextWeights = new TextWeights()
                        {
                            Weights = new Dictionary<string, double>()
                            {
                                {"Fname",2} ,
                                {"Lname",2} ,
                                {"Mname",0.3} ,
                                {"DOB",3} ,
                                {"DriversLicense",6} ,
                                {"IdentificationNumber",6} ,
                                {"PhoneCell",4} ,
                                {"Gender",0.2} ,
                                {"PhoneHome",1} ,
                            }
                        }
                    },
                }
```

for searching i am thinking i need to use lucene Fielded query operation, but i do not see any example on how to do this using azure search sdk for c#.  i will be passing all or some of the attributes above and i am expecting them to be matched against their respective attributes and property like name should be allowed to do fuzzy match as well. then to get top 5 results in descending order of score.

Answer (score 0):

Justin,

I am not sure what you actual question above is.

That said, if the question is how to pass the Lucene query to the .NET SDK.

This is just the searchText parameter of the `[Search method][1]` (or SearchAsync, or SearchWithHttpMessagesAsync, or one of its generic overloads, etc.).

Thanks!

-Luis Cabrera